# Why does my PID controller spin my spaceship out of control?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, pid-controller

I'm working in Unity, trying my hand at a simple spaceship game. I was trying to control pitch and yaw with a single joystick control. So I take the input of the x or y axis on the joystick and use that as my set point for angular velocity. Then I have a little pid controller that tries to keep things under control. It works great if I use one axis, but the second I use both it spins wildly out of control.

This is the pid controller, pretty simple:

```
public class pid : MonoBehaviour
{
public float pFactor, iFactor, dFactor;

float integral;
float lastError;


public pid(float pFactor, float iFactor, float dFactor)
{
    this.pFactor = pFactor;
    this.iFactor = iFactor;
    this.dFactor = dFactor;
}


public float Update(float setpoint, float actual, float timeFrame)
{
    float present = setpoint - actual;
    integral += present * timeFrame;
    float deriv = (present - lastError) / timeFrame;
    lastError = present;
    return present * pFactor + integral * iFactor + deriv * dFactor;
}
}
```

And here is my torque update code where I apply torque to the ship (inside fixed update).

```
float yawUpdate = mYawPid.Update(move.x*5, mRigidbody.angularVelocity.y, Time.deltaTime);
Debug.Log("setpoint " + move.x + "actual " + mRigidbody.angularVelocity.y + " yawupdate " +  yawUpdate.ToString());
mRigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.up * yawUpdate);

float pitchUpdate = mPitchPid.Update(move.y*5, mRigidbody.angularVelocity.x, Time.deltaTime);
Debug.Log("setpoint " + move.y + "actual " + mRigidbody.angularVelocity.x + " pitchupdate " + pitchUpdate.ToString());
mRigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.right * pitchUpdate);


float rollUpdate = mPitchPid.Update(0, mRigidbody.angularVelocity.z, Time.deltaTime);
//Debug.Log("setpoint " + move.y + "actual " + mRigidbody.angularVelocity.x + " pitchupdate " + pitchUpdate.ToString());
mRigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.forward * rollUpdate);
```

Now I also tried AddTorque instead of AddRelativeTorque and that is stable, no wild spinning. But now my ship pitches based on whatever is facing the camera. So if I rotated it right by 90 degrees, now when I pitch the nose won't dip it'll do a barrel roll. I don't get what I'm doing wrong yet.  Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: First of all you should use `AddRelativeTorque` since you want the space ship to rotate oriented to it's own coordinate system. That being said I don't know exactly why your code, but maybe try calculating all three in advance, store them into a single Vector3 and call `mRigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(pitch, yaw, roll));`

Comment: I thought of solution when I was falling asleep :).  I need relative torque and relative angular velocity!  Found a post on unity forum that said Vector3 localangularvelocity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(rigidbody.angularVelocity);

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]

Comment: Read tags before applying them.  This has nothing to do with the [tag:pid] tag, which is about process ids.  [tag:unityscript] is about a JS-like language that was deprecated a few years ago.